# Should I return a 4xx error even if the result is good?

Tags: rest

I'm building a file uploader. I've created a "stat" endpoint which can be used to get some information about a file, given a filename.

I'm using it to determine if the file already exists on the server before the upload begins.

Right now I have "stat" returning a 404 if the file doesn't exist. But this is actually a *good* thing because it means there's no conflict.

Chrome highlights it in red because it thinks its bad, but it kind of makes sense for REST, no?

Or should I change it to a 2xx code and just say that it doesn't exist in the JSON data instead?

Comment: RESTfully, returning the correct header code for what your API does would be the correct approach. Don't worry about what Chrome says, just handle the header codes appropriately in your client.